# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum(nx)^{-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to check for uniform convergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(nx)^2}$ on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$

Here's what I've tried:

If $|x|\ge 1$ then $(nx)^2\geq n^2$ so that $\dfrac{1}{(nx)^2}\leq\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and by Weirstrass M test the series is uniformly convergent.

I am not sure how to proceed for $|x|<1$. One thing I observe is $f_n(1/n)=1$ but I'm not sure if that helps.

Is it possible to do it without knowing that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $N \in \mathbb N$ we can choose $n,m \ge N$ such that $\sup\{|S_n(x) - S_m(x)| : x \in \mathbb R-\{0\}\} > \epsilon$, where $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x^2k^2}$

We'll choose $\epsilon$ later. Now consider $|S_{2n}(x) - S_n(x)|$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.

$|S_{2n}(x) - S_n(x)| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{x^2k^2}$. Now if we take $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then we have $\sup\{|S_{2n}(x) - S_{n}(x)| : x \in \mathbb R-\{0\}\} > |S_{2n}(x_n) - S_n(x_n)| = n^2 \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2} > n^2 \frac{n}{4n^2}= \frac{n}{4} \to \infty$.

So taking $\epsilon = 1$, and any $N \in \mathbb N$, we can choose $n = \max\{N,10\}, m=2n$ for it to work, which clearly means, the convergence cannot be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $$\sup_{x \neq 0}|\frac{1}{x^2}(\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6})|=|\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}|\sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{1}{x^2}=+\infty$$

So the covergence is not uniform.

Comment: Why do you delete one answer and then post an identical one?

Comment: Because i had a downvote to a different answer,the i edited my answer which i believe is correct and i do not want for the O.P to think it is wrong because of the downvote

Comment: @MariosGretsas I actually don't understand how you computed the supremum

Comment: as $x \to 0$ we have that $\frac{1}{x^2} \to +\infty$

Answer (score 0):

If the convergence was uniform, $\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb R \setminus\{0\}} (nx)^{-2}$ would converge to $0$ with $n$. But this is not the case as this value is always greater than $1$.